# Interpolation to generate elements?

Tags: interpolation

I have a list with values at some points:

```
 list1 = {{0.0, 0.001119484321}, {0.80, 0.001128926919}, {1.6, 
0.001120999228}, {2.4, 0.001086309651}, {3.2, 
0.001114222604}, {4.0, 0.001059617102}, {4.8, 
0.000840821088}, {5.4, 0.000513081122}};
```

Now I want to generate value at following points by interpolating the above data (interpolation order 3):

```
points = Table[i, {i, 0, 5, 0.25}];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly different approach:

```
int = Interpolation[list1, InterpolationOrder -> 3]
```

Using this to compute values for new points:

```
int[Range[0, 5, 0.25]]
```

> `{0.00111948, 0.00112373, 0.00112692, 0.00112875, 0.00112894, \
>   0.00112721, 0.00112326, 0.00111384, 0.00110141, 0.00109074, \
>   0.00108935, 0.00109937, 0.00110931, 0.00111407, 0.0011078, \
>   0.00109048, 0.00105962, 0.00101325, 0.000948008, 0.000861064, \
>   0.000749579}`

And this is visual comparison (new points are in red):

```
 Show[Plot[int[x], {x, 0, 5.4}], 
 ListPlot[list1, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, PointSize[Medium]]], 
 ListPlot[Transpose[{Range[0, 5, 0.25], int[Range[0, 5, 0.25]]}], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Medium]]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
y = Fit[list1, {1, x, x^2, x^3}, x];

y /. x -> Range[0, 5, .25]
```

{ 0.00113979, 0.00111488, 0.00109939, 0.00109181, 0.00109067, 
0.00109447, 0.00110173, 0.00111096, 0.00112068, 0.0011294, 
0.00113563, 0.00113788, 0.00113467, 0.00112451, 0.00110591, 
0.0010774, 0.00103747, 0.000984644, 0.000917436, 0.000834359, 
0.000733924}

Your original points in red, the interpolated points in green:

[image]